# Error models.py Django

Tags: python, django, migrate, makemigrations

I have an error when creating migrations in django

models.py

```
class StateBuyers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "states"

class CountiesBuyers (models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(StateBuyers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "counties"


class CityBuyers (models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(StateBuyers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    county = models.ForeignKey(CountiesBuyers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "cities"
```

maybe here I have the error
create one instance of many

```
class Buyers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    state = models.ForeignKey(StateBuyers, related_name="Buyers", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(CityBuyers, related_name="Buyers", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField (max_length= 50)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "buyers"
```

At the time of migration throws this error
Any ideas ?.

[migration error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B53hq.png)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: this. return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "buyers" does not exist

Comment: You can not use the same `related_name` for two FK, change it and try again.

Comment: same error, any ideas ?

Comment: you maybe need to delete/edit the last migration file generated with the error, that's why you get the same error.

Comment: same mistake friend, any idea?

Comment: Try removing the "s" from the Buyers class name, and just call it Buyer.  It is a Django convention to not be plural. This may also be the conflict since it's the name of the `related_name` on the two fields.

Comment: same error, any idea?????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slightly off-topic, but why do you not follow the conventions?

- simple model names using *singular* form
- no need for extra parameters if they are same as defaults
- why duplicate State if there is State for county? any performance gains?

```
class NameAsReprMixin(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class State(models.Model, NameAsReprMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)    


class County(models.Model, NameAsReprMixin):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class City(models.Model, NameAsReprMixin):
    county = models.ForeignKey(County)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Buyer(models.Model, NameAsReprMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name="buyers", null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name="buyers", null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length= 50)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

then:

```
# all city buyers
City.object.get(...).buyers.all()

# all state byuers
State.object.get(...).buyers.all()
```

Comment: ok brother thanks, 
now I get this error, any ideas?
http://i67.tinypic.com/24eddu0.png
help!

Comment: @JesusRobles try now, fixed code (I was writing from memory), btw, for the code & stacktrace use gist - much better :)